# What does it mean for void to be a "first class type"?

Tags: programming-languages

As the title says, and what are the benefits of this? The question was inspired by [Microsoft's research language](http://joeduffyblog.com/2013/12/27/csharp-for-systems-programming/).

Comment: My take on this is that they'd like to make `void` become a type, not a syntactic device to indicate the absense of a value (or having no information on the type of a value for the case of `void*`).  I have no idea what this could be useful for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a first-class type means `void` could be used anywhere a type annotation is allowed. In C#, `void` can only be used as a return type for a method, but all of the following are illegal:

```
// A void parameter type.
int SomeMethod(void parameter) { ... }

// A void type argument.
List<void>

// A void variable.
void Main()
{
  void someVar;
}
```

Java *does* have a first-class void type, spelled `Void` (note the capital "V"). It's useful sometimes in generics. It only has one value, `null`.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but I failed to understand how something like that could be useful until I found this http://www.glenmccl.com/ansi_023.htm

Answer (score 0):

If void is a first class type then you can use it when defining variables.  I think a void variable could be used as a pointer to pass a something like a function or an object if you recast it I guess.  It would give you an ability to do dynamic type casts.

Comment: The value of a void variable could be used in the same way as the result of calling a void function: not at all. What you're talking about would be a void pointer.